# Godot crashing because of two CanvasLayers in the scene

Tags: godot

I have in my level scene a CanvasLayer to my background.
Now, I want to add the UI so I created another CanvasLayer for the UI to display above the game.
But, I soon as I loaded the CanvasLayer (and the UI inside) into the game, The game freeze and crash after seconds without error or stacktrace.

I tried to delete th bg CanvasLayer - and it worked.
It's also not a problem in the layer number, or any other thing i could test.
As soon as there are 2 CanvasLayers in the scene (also include sub scene with CanvasLayer
insde) the game Crashes.

Can someone help with this bug?

Godot version 4.0.2

Comment: Make a project with just the minimum required to reproduce the problem, and open an issue attaching it, here: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues

Comment: An 2d node with only canvas layer with textureRect an other canvas layer for control node with progress bar inside counts?

Comment: the renderer is Compability (if thats helps)

Comment: @sss Could you please update your answer with more details like: Important scripts attached to canvas layers, and screenshot or description of node layout.